# How to create a 2D array inside xml in android?

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to create a **2D array** inside *arrays.xml* in android.Can someone point it out with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be impossible: Google yields this.

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg01672.html